# ast.literal_eval for variables in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I have a file `example.py`:
    import example

```
VVV = 2

DictionaryNameB = {
    'a'                   : VVV,
    'bb'                  : 'SomethingB',
    'c'                   : False,
    'ccc'                 : None,
    'dddd'                : 'true',
    'eeeee'               : 0.123456,
    'f'                   : 2,
    'h'                   : [1,2,3]
}
```

I wrote a function that uses `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
def getDicFromFile(self, dic_name):
    with open( 'example.py' ) as f:
        file_data = f.read()
    match = re.findall('%s[^{]+\{[^\}]+\}' % dic_name, file_data, re.MULTILINE)[0]
    # print(match)
    dicObject = ast.literal_eval(match[len(dic_name)+3:])
    return dicObject
```

I got the error raise ValueError('malformed string') ; ValueError: malformed string

I understand that `ast.literal_eval()` can't decode the variable `VVV`, is there another way to do it?

Comment: see [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: Just *import* the file.

Comment: @behzad.nouri: `eval()` only supports expressions, not statements. Assignment is a statement, so that won't work.

Comment: If you don't trust the contents of the file, then it's very difficult to execute it safely.  If you do trust the contents of the file, then simply import it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`asteval`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asteval), a library that builds on the `ast` parse tree to execute limited statements. It'll handle your example out of the box:

```
from asteval import Interpreter

aeval = Interpreter()
aeval(file_data)
dicObject = aeval.symtable['DictionaryNameB']
```

Or, you could just import the file:

```
from importlib import import_module
module = import_module('example')
dicObject = module.DictionaryNameB
```

`asteval` allows for quite a wide number of Python constructs. You could compare the [Python Abstract Grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) with what handlers the `aeval.node_handlers` mapping registers, and simply delete any you don't need. You could remove function definitions and calling, looping, binary operations (`binop`) and exception handling, for example.

Comment: what do you mean import the file ?

Comment: @omertalmi: `import example` would load the file as a Python module.

Comment: asteval does a good job protecting against known attack vectors, *except* for resource hogging:  9**9**9 will still consume all your time and/or memory.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: but tuning it back a little (by removing AST node names from `Interpreter.node_handlers`) is luckily dead easy. :-)