# `ast.literal_eval` equivalent for custom class objects?

Tags: python

`ast.literal_eval` works well for evaluating python's inbuilt types:

```
In [42]: import ast

In [43]: ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3, "4", None, (5, 4, 3)]')
Out[43]: [1, 2, 3, '4', None, (5, 4, 3)]
```

It fails for custom class objects:

```
In [44]: class Foo():
    ...:     def __init__(self, val):
    ...:         self.val = val
    ...:  

In [45]: ast.literal_eval('[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-a3bd4f494d5d> in <module>()
----> 1 ast.literal_eval('[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]')
```

But, `eval` works just fine:

```
In [46]: eval('[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]')
Out[46]: 
[<__main__.Foo at 0x107e13940>,
 <__main__.Foo at 0x107e131d0>,
 <__main__.Foo at 0x107e13160>]
```

How can I combine the safety of `ast.literal_eval` with the functionality of `eval` for custom objects?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867475/ast-literal-eval-for-variables-in-python) but this pertains to variables that already exist.

Comment: function calls are not *literals*. A literal is a *string literal*, an *integer literal*, `True`, `False`, `None`, *list literal*, *tuple literal*, *set literal* and *dictionary literal*.

Comment: e.g. `ast.literal_eval('dict()')` fails as well. Since you could have overwritten `dict(..)` in your code. All calls - regardless whether these are builtins or not - will fail.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So bottom line, there's no solution?

Comment: You can construct a custom `ast` that will allow certain things. But i would use whitelisting instead of blacklisting.

Answer (score 1):

if your data was like this -

```
'["Foo(1)", "Foo(2)", "Foo(3)"]'
```

literal_eval would have worked. 
Because it would think that Foo(1) and others are strings and would recognize them.

```
'[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]'
```

As far as I know, this cannot be used as argument in literal_eval.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval),

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.